# Transform dragging on movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

So here's the problem in video form

https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CPsvjgbWoAACKCp.mp4

When not moving the ship the shield moves around just fine, but when you start moving it can only drag behind you and move a little bit, which is just no good at all. I can't figure out what I've done wrong here!

```
public class ShieldMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target; //player shield is attaced to
public float circSpeed = 0.1f; // Speed Shield moves around ship

private Vector3 direction = Vector3.up;
private float distance = 0.8f; // distance from player so it doesn't clip
private float deadzone = 0.15f;
private float separation;
private bool canMove = true;

private Vector3 shipPos;

private Rigidbody2D tRB;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    tRB = target.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other) 
{
    canMove = false;
}

void OnCollisionStay2d(Collision2D other)
{
    canMove = false;
}

void OnCollisionExit2D (Collision2D other) 
{
    canMove = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float rh = Input.GetAxisRaw("rightH");
    float rv = Input.GetAxisRaw("rightV");

    shipPos = target.position;

    separation = Mathf.Abs((transform.position - shipPos).magnitude);

    if(Mathf.Abs(rh) > deadzone || Mathf.Abs(rv) > deadzone)
    {
        Vector3 targetDir = new Vector3(rh, rv, 0.0f);
        direction  = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position-shipPos, targetDir, circSpeed);

    }

    Ray ray = new Ray(shipPos, direction); // cast ray in direction of point on circle shield is to go

    if(canMove)
    {
        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance); //move shield to the ray as far as the distance
    }

    if(separation != distance) //If the shield get torn away from the ship
    {
        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance); //move shield to the ray as far as the distance
    }

    float angleY = transform.position.y - shipPos.y;
    float angleX = -(transform.position.x - shipPos.x);

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (angleY, angleX) * Mathf.Rad2Deg-90; //Get angle

    if(Mathf.Abs(rh) > deadzone || Mathf.Abs(rv) > deadzone)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle,Vector3.forward*-1); // keep shield facing outwards in respect to player
    }


}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(!canMove)
    {

        tRB.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    }
}
```

Thanks a million for any help :)

Comment: Have a look at the `RotateAround()` function, it might suit your purposes better: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: I tried RotateAround() but it only seems to spin the shield on its own axis at the location given, where I need to change the transforms position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the shield along with the ship. You can do this by adding the ship velocity to the shield.
Something like:

```
shipPos = target.position;
transform.position += shipVelocity;
separation = Mathf.Abs((transform.position - shipPos).magnitude);
```

Or make the shield a child object of the ship.

Comment: Childing the shield worked after I got rid of the conditional statement around the 'transform.rotation' the more you know! lol

Answer (score 0):

OK, so all I needed to do was to make the shield a child AND get rid of the conditional statement around the `transform.rotation` so it wouldn't inherit the parent rotation and ruin the shield. It's the little things!